# How to choose the "Key" for inter-processes communication in Linux?

Tags: linux, ipc, message-passing

Good Day...

I am doing a homework which states that I have 5 processes; a server and the rest are clients. **Each process is supposed to be sparked from a different executable**. I am going to implement a two-way message passing solution, but the question is not about message passing per se. Is there an elegant way to communicate the ***key*** between those different executables. i.e. when I call the following function:

```
int msgget(key_t key, int msgflg);
```

**How are other processes  supposed to know the key?**

It is OK for my homework to use a predetermined key, but I would like to know how it could be done in a real program. Because What "I understand" is there could happen a conflict if an unrelated process asks for the my key in some user's machine.

Answer (score 11):

one convention is to use [ftok()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftok) to generate a unique key, from [man](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftok)

> The ftok() function uses the identity
>   of the file named by the given
>   pathname (which must refer to an
>   existing, accessible file) and the
>   least significant 8 bits of proj_id
>   (which must be non-zero) to generate a
>   key_t type System V IPC key, suitable
>   for use with msgget(2), semget(2), or
>   shmget(2).
>
> The resulting value is the same for
>   all pathnames that name the same file,
>   when the same value of proj_id is
>   used. The value returned should be
>   different when the (simultaneously
>   existing) files or the project IDs
>   differ.

Comment: Thanks. Excuse me If I understood the answer incorrectly, but how do I share that "generated key" between the executables? i.e. After I get the key in the server, how would I communicate it to one of the clients?

Comment: By running ftok with the same argument in the clients.

Comment: @hobbs If I read the description correctly, it says that there must exist a file in that path, so predetermined random "long" string is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you'd typically generate a psuedorandom key for your program, and embed that in there. There are 2^32 possible keys, so the chance of a collision is fairly tiny.

If you need to guarantee no accidental collision, you'd typically use a named pipe instead of message passing.

Comment: Thats why came to my mind actually, maybe I am assuming that collision could happen where in fact it doesn't happen in practice. I would choose this answer if no other solution is proposed :)

Answer (score 1):

For "global" resources I'm seconding jspcal's `ftok()` answer which he got in just ahead of me with :)

If you have a bunch of related processes (that is, a parent and a bunch of children) and they should share a queue, then you should call msgget with `IPC_PRIVATE` which will create a queue with an unused key and return the handle to it.